# Расположение JPanel в окне с помощью FlowLayout

Tags: java, java-8, awt

Подскажите, как переместить JPanel с середины сверху (по умолчанию) влево по середине? `GridLayout` хранит в себе поле кнопок 3х3 - все это содержится в `panel`, я добавил еще одну панель (`p`) и поставил `FlowLayout.Left`, но все равно не получилось. Я думаю, что мне нужно компоновать `Layout`ы, но я не знаю как.
Код:

```
 package res;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Source extends JPanel {
    private JPanel panel, p;
    private  JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9;
    //private char x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3;
    private boolean gameInit, playerWon, compWon;

    public Source(){
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        field();
    }

    public void field(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        b1 = new JButton();
        b2 = new JButton();
        b3 = new JButton();
        b4 = new JButton();
        b5 = new JButton();
        b6 = new JButton();
        b7 = new JButton();
        b8 = new JButton();
        b9 = new JButton();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(b2);
        panel.add(b3);
        panel.add(b4);
        panel.add(b5);
        panel.add(b6);
        panel.add(b7);
        panel.add(b8);
        panel.add(b9);
        add(panel);

        p = new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        p.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        p.add(panel);
        add(p);
    }
}
```

UPD: `BorderLayout` не работает в строке `p.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));` (Вместо `FlowLayout`).

Пожалуйста, не предлагайте сделать это через массив. Я пытаюсь практиковаться основываясь на полученных знаниях и позже оптимизирую код сам. Заранее спасибо!

[image: Вот то, что получается]

Comment: Если не сложно, дополните код минимальным примером для запуска

Comment: @ezhov_da добавил скриншот

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось просто: Source стремиться стать `JPanel`, поэтому в `public Source(){}` мы должны описать, как себя будут вести объекты на нем. Вообщем дописываем `setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));` и все